# Convert an html template to a vector PDF

Tags: html, node.js, pdf

I'm struggling to find a working package (preferably client side) for converting HTML templates to PDF form. Then I found the [node-html-pdf](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf) package.

I'm not sure whether it's possible to avoid saving on the server and serving it directly to the client.
Anyone had any experience with this package?

**Edit:**
I also found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/front-pdfkit but came out with the following 2 issues:

1. Non-english characters are displayed in weird characters
2. I'm not quite sure how to serve it to the client (I don't want to save anything on the server)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see an actual programming question here? The only question I ssee is "has anyone used this package before", which is [not the kind of question](/help/on-topic) that Stackoverflow is for. What do you actually need to do? (e.g. why do you even need to convert HTML to PDF, client side? What are you doing that requires this?)

Comment: Perhaps I indeed started generally but now I specified my issue

Comment: Not in your post you haven't. Please remember to read through ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) because right now your post might make sense to you, but it certainly doesn't make sense to me. It feels like you've left off the bits that actually explain your situation, and the only _actual question_ is still "does anyone have any experience with this package" in which case: that's 100% off topic and not something to ask on Stackoverflow, as this is not a general help forum. It is a very specific kind of help forum, with policies on which kind of questions are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for the [html-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-pdf) package which uses the flyingsaucer java library which can be handy while generating large sized pdf's (especially on the client side).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you David! I been digging into this library. But as it appears, it doesn't support vector texts. These PDF are meant to be printed so it needs to be vector. Perhaps I should test it by printing because by far this is the simplest library I've seen (+ It's client side)

Comment: In such case try considering the [front-pdfkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/front-pdfkit) library which I guess has support for the vector.

Comment: Okay, that's already looks more promising. Two things I have to solve: 1. Non-english document is displayed with weird letters. 2. Serve it to the client. I'm editing my main thread)